# How to define propTypes for a Component that only passes props to a Child

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-proptypes

What is the best practice to define proptypes in a Parent that only passes props to a Child without using it?

Simple use case:

```
const Parent = ({ p0, p1 }) => (
  <section className="Parent">
    <div>I'm the parent</div>
    <p>{p0}</p>
    <Child p1={p1} />
  </section>
);

Parent.propTypes = {
  p0: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  // p1 ?
};
```

And the child component:

```
const Child = ({ p1 }) => (
  <section className="Child">
    <div>I'm a Child</div>
    <span>{p1}</span>
  </section>
);

Child.propTypes = {
  p1: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

Here the options for the Parent :

1. Do not define p1 propTypes and use *// disable-eslint-next-line react/propTypes*
2. `p1: PropTypes.any.isRequired`
3. `p1: Child.propTypes.p1` (What if Child is exported with React.memo ?)
4. Use the same type as Child `p1: PropTypes.string.isRequired` (if Child has 10 props it can be really boring to duplicate all proptypes)
5. Other solution

Online example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-bush-3u243

Comment: just use context if `Parent` is just a pass-through (not using `p1`)

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand your code, even tough `p1` is passed on to the `Child`, it is *still* part of the implementation of `Parent`. Logically, it is also required in `Parent` too.

So it is correct that you have to define it in the `Parent`'s prop types too.

But I understand that the code can be tedious, but this is more a matter of style than of technical correctness, and styles are prone to change as paradigms and tastes change all the time. So I guess there is no right or wrong answer here, only flavors.

Of course there are some concepts here that you might be able to apply. There is always a discussion on coupling or decoupling code, the latter sometimes advocating code duplication (duplicating the prop types). But then again your prop types can run out of sync if you change on component but not the other.

Personally I would load the prop types from the Child and merge the ones you want to use into the parent:

```
import Child from "./Child";

const Parent = ({ p0, p1 }) => {/* ... */}

const { p1 } = Child.propTypes;

Parent.propTypes = {
  p0: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  p1
};
```

Comment: Also side note, if you use TypeScript all of this is implicit and sometimes you would put prop interfaces into their own files that you can import. The latter you could also do here.

Comment: thanks, according to your example what if Child is wrapped ?
example : export default React.memo(Child);

Comment: Then they can be accessible through `React.memo(Child).type.propTypes`, see `Parent.js` in https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-smoke-niffo but I would not advise you to do that. We're then in a realm of hacks and anti-patterns. You could make the prop types their own export, see `Child.js` in that sandbox, but that starts to seem bad too. Then we're back where you have to compare code styles.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just extend the Child propTypes from the Parent propTypes

```
Parent.propTypes = {
  ...{
    p0: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }, ...Child.propTypes
};
```

I think this should work.

P.S. I know this code does not look very good, but you can probably use a library like lodash or Object.assign to make it prettier. Maybe even create a method to extend propTypes.

I hope it helps

Comment: your first spread is not necessary : 
`Parent.propTypes = {
    p0: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    ...Child.propTypes
};
` but if Child is wrapped it will not work (ex: export default React.memo(Child))

Comment: in that case, you can create an interface and export it, i.e.

`export const ChildPropTypes = PropTypes.shape({
  p1: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
});`

and then 

`Parent.propTypes = {
  {
    p0: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }, ...ChildPropTypes
};
`

thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I would say it depends on the nature of props:

**Case 1: The props are vital data/state for your application**

In this case, I would say require the props in both the parent and the child.

**Case 2: The props are required by the child, but they are not so important - meaning, the parent can as well make them up**

In this case, I suggest you don't require the props. Set prop types and set default props.

**Note:** In either case, use the same prop types for the child and the parent to ensure predictability in the application. Allowing any prop types for the parent and requiring let's say strings for the child would create a mess in the application - it's always better to be sure of which type of data to expect where than encourage ambiguity.

**Second Note:** If you find yourself passing several props from the parent to the child ( let's say the parent expects 10 props and you pass 8 to the child ), you may need to refactor your code to get rid of the parent because she may not be that important - but of course you are the judge of the level of importance here.

**Third Note:** Use the disabling of react prop-types sparingly. It is a quick way to escape problems but it is also an easy way to create an application in which you don't know which types of data are flowing around.